# Why does minified jQuery 3.4.1 have duplicate event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently updated a site from jQuery 2.2.0 to 3.4.1. Both before and after the update, I used the minified version of jQuery. For some reason, the minified version of 3.4.1 adds a second copy of every event handler. It also includes a DOM2 and Bubbling tag, and always has the same code. If I run with the developer copy of 3.4.1 (so, unminified), these extra event handlers are not present. I'm testing this in Mozilla Firefox. ** When I tested in Google chrome, I noticed there is not duplicates.

I've confirmed this happens when I add any event handler to even a new element (that I manually appended through the console). Is there some sort of configuration problem?

The code present in the "duplicate" handler.

```
function(e) {
  return "undefined" != typeof k && k.event.triggered !== e.type ? k.event.dispatch.apply(t, arguments) : void 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me, when I tried to print out the result of my function with an *alert* as:

```
function weapon_form_control(){
    $('#dps-meter-weapon').find('input').bind('input',function(){
        var k=$('#dps-meter-weapon').find('.weapon-name').val;

        alert(k);   
    });
}
```

In this example, I forgot to add `()` after `.val` and the function tried to print the full code of `element.val` jQuery function instead of the result of its work as: `<input>` value.